# Can java code start on war file deploy and run in background on wildfly server?

Tags: java, wildfly

Can java code inside war file start on war file deploy and run in background on Wildfly server without stopping?

If this is not correct place to ask - where should i ask this question?

Thank you

Comment: You should use @ singleton @ startup annotations

Comment: @WillT Thank you. I shall google these annotations, but maybe you could provide an example?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do?